# script for monitor local port using check_mk

Tags: shell, check-mk

I have a server with runs nodejs applications in multiple ports. those ports are not publically accessible. I want to monitor those ports using check_mk .
How can I do this

Comment: Hi, welcome to the SO club. Try to update your question and make it a bit more clear. Also please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)! Thanks.

Comment: Requests for tutorials, documentation, etc are off-topic here. StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems. Your Q seems  more appropriate for https://superuser.com or https://serverfault.com , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the port that nodejs uses by developing a plugin.
server side, checking port 3306:

#!/bin/bash

mysql3306=`netstat -an | grep LISTEN | grep 3306 | awk '{print $4}' | sed 's/://g'`

echo "<<<checks_ports>>>"
if [ "$mysql3306" == "3306" ]
then
echo "3306 1"
else
echo "3306 0"
fi

Then you need to do the checks on the server check_mk